# Windows batch file - For All files in given directory and subdirectories - change file extension to lowercase

Tags: windows, batch-file

My aim: Use Windows batch script to ensure that all files within given directory and subdirectories have a file extension that is lowercase

I have managed to get this far (not very far I admit !)..

```
for /R c:\test %%G in (*.*) do (
  echo %%G
)
```

this successfully prints out all files with an extension (inc full path) but how do I check the file extension and ensure it is lowercase (I do not want to make the filename lowercase by the way .. just the extension).

Thanks in advance !

Greg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 (possibly 3) techniques you need to accomplish your task.

1) You need to parse out the file name and file extension - that is trivial as described in the FOR HELP. (type `HELP FOR` from the command line)

- `%%~nG` = file name
- `%%~xG` = file extension

2) You need to store each file extension in a variable and then use code like the following to convert it to lowercase

```
for %%C in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "ext=!ext:%%C=%%C!"
```

You will need to enable delayed expansion with `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the top of the script.

The above works because the search portion of search and replace is case insensitive.

3) In the unlikely situation that a file extension might containn a `!`, you need to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop. But I seriously doubt you will run into that situation.

Here is a finished, functioning script that disregards point 3.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r "c:\test" %%F in (*) do if "%%~xF" neq "" (
  set "ext=%%~xF"
  for %%C in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "ext=!ext:%%C=%%C!"
  ren "%%F" "%%~nF!ext!"
)
```

Bali C had an interesting idea in his answer, but it did not quite work. I managed to make it work by creating a temporary file with a name consisting only of the file extension in a temporary folder. But it is slower than the above solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "folder=%temp%\ren%random%"
md "%folder%"
for /r "c:\test" %%F in (*) do if "%%~xF" neq "" (
  copy nul "%folder%\%%~xF" >nul
  for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /b /l "%folder%"') do ren "%%F" "%%~nF%%X"
  del /q "%folder%"
)
rd "%folder%"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rushed but something to work with

```
for /r C:\Folder %%a in (*) do (
    for /f %%s in ('dir /b /l %%a') do (
        ren %%a %%~na%%~xs
    )
)
```

The `dir` command with the `/l` switch is what turns it into lowercase, but from the testing I have done it works sometimes and not others.

Hopefully this can be improved on by another member, but it should work in theory.

Comment: Interesting idea, but the `%%~xs` expands to the native case of the file name. The lower case produced by DIR /L is lost.

Comment: +1; Although your code does not work, it is the basis of the 2nd working solution in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't work out how to keep the version that `dir` created, I thought about using a temporary file but couldn't get my head around it :)